# Edit review long after approval

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

Is it normal that I was able to edit a review 19 hours after it was approved?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16666395

Comment: Did you leave the review page open for 19 hours (opening it when it still wasn't completed)?

Comment: @Servy, likely.

Comment: Then yes, that'd be intentional.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that the edit *you* made was incorrect.  You shouldn't be editing posts to change their code like that.  The edit that was suggested was actually the correct edit, pointing out that the newer version of the language had changed without removing the solution for the previous version.

Comment: @Servy the ecosystem of UIKit is particular: Apple only supports an old syntax for a limited time. Documentation itself is now using Swift 4 syntax. When one chooses Swift over Objective-C, then migrating the code syntax each year is a requirement.

Comment: I've added a note to mention the legacy name used previously in the post.

Comment: @Cœur I don't know anything about Swift, but maybe should you have posted an answer with fresh code instead of editing the old one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's intentional that if you open a review page of an unreviewed edit, and then approve/reject it and also edit it, that the edit will be applied *even if another user has since approved or rejected the edit in the meantime*.

You won't overturn the review decision, it will stay approved or rejected based on the earlier decision, but it will still count as a review, and the actual edit will be applied.

If you would have simply approved or rejected the edit without also editing it, then it would have counted as you making a review, and you'd show up in the page as a reviewer, but you again wouldn't actually change the review decision.